# В массив не заносит string более 1024

Tags: php, mysql

Версия php 7.0. Из базы в массив вывожу значения (GROUP_CONCAT), заметил что выводит не все, на выходе получается массив **["ip"]=> string(1024)** , и больше в него не лезет..

как быть?

Comment: `mysql> SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;` Это установит максимальную длину _GROUP_CONCAT_ быть 1000000

Comment: @KostaB. а как его применить?

Comment: @KostaB. а как применить это не понял.... у меня mysqli

Comment: Зайти в phpMyAdmin или командную строку MySQL и применить =) как запросы применяете, или применить в конфиг файле `group_concat_max_len = 1000000` под  `[mysqld]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По совершенному загадочному совпадению настройка mysql [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) как раз по умолчанию равна 1024. Почему бы это?..

Иначе говоря, ваша проблема не имеет совершенно никакого отношения к PHP. И является задокументированным поведением агрегирующей функции [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) в mysql. По достижении размера данных в group_concat_max_len байт, дальнейшие данные будут тихо отбрасываться.

Comment: а как установить больше?

Comment: поменять в конфиге глобально или изменить на текущую сессию запросом `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = ?`. На мой взгляд лучше переработать логику запросов и не использовать GROUP_CONCAT там, где может расти объём данных.

Comment: как это сделать в этом запросе? `$myPartner = $mysqli->query("SELECT `date`, GROUP_CONCAT(`ip` SEPARATOR ' ') `ip` FROM `partner` WHERE `id_user` = '$us[id]' GROUP BY date(`date`) DESC");`